# Message queue in linux

Tags: linux, message-queue, garbage

In linux, what should be the output of message queue, when message queue is empty?

First I have send 2 message in one message queue then I have received 2 message from message queue. Now again I am trying to receive message from message queue then I am getting garbage value. Then tell me why I am getting this garbage value ?

**Receive.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main() 
{
   int msqid;

   struct message 
   {
      long type;
      char text[20];
   } msg;

   struct msqid_ds buf;

   int msgtype = 3;
   int num_messages;
   int count;
   int key = 1234;

   msqid = msgget(key,0644);

   count = msgctl(msqid,IPC_STAT,&buf);
   num_messages = buf.msg_qnum;

   printf("Number of messages = %d\n",num_messages);

   if (msgrcv(msqid, (void *) &msg, sizeof(msg.text), msgtype, MSG_NOERROR| IPC_NOWAIT)==-1);
   {  
    perror("msgrcv");           
   }

   /*  if(num_messages==0)
       {
              printf("Queue is empty\n");
       }
       else
       {  */   
           printf("%s \n", msg.text);
    // }

       return 0;
 }
```

**Send.c**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/msg.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    struct message 
    {
        long type;
        char text[20];
    } msg;

    int msqid;
    int key = 1234;
    msqid = msgget(key,IPC_CREAT|0644);

    msg.type = 3;
    strcpy(msg.text, "This is message 1");
    msgsnd(msqid, (void *) &msg, sizeof(msg.text), IPC_NOWAIT);
    strcpy(msg.text, "This is message 2");
    msgsnd(msqid, (void *) &msg, sizeof(msg.text), IPC_NOWAIT);

    printf("2 messages are succesfully send \n");
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the return value of `msgrcv` (you do that already) and `errno`. From [`msgrcv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgop.2.html) documentation:

> `IPC_NOWAIT` Return immediately if no message of the requested type is in the queue.  The system call fails with `errno` set to `ENOMSG`.

If you ignore the failure and try to read `msg`, its values are going to be undetermined because it was not initialized. E.g.:

```
if(msgrcv(msqid, &msg, sizeof(msg.text), msgtype, MSG_NOERROR | IPC_NOWAIT))
{
    if(ENOMSG == errno)
        fprintf(stderr, "No messages found\n");
    else
        perror("msgrcv");
}
else {
    // Successfully received a message into msg.
}
```

(Note that in the original code you have a semi-colon after `if`, which is probably not what you want).

Comment: I have attached my Output Image

Comment: ultimately I want to know that why this garbage value comes after receiving all messages from message queue

Comment: Will you please tell how to check this failure of "msgrcv" function?? please modify my code. It will be really helpful to me

Comment: If you dont know then tell me frankly.. bou don't bluff.

Comment: if you don't know how to solve this then tell me frankly. but don't bluff

Comment: then please upload it properly so that I can understand.. I am not getting what you are trying to convey

Comment: @user3571717 Refresh the page in the browser and read my updated answer.

Comment: It will give me an error that "ENOMSG" is undefined.

Comment: will you please tell me why this garbage value comes? can you tell me the reason?

Comment: Still I am not getting Output

Comment: @user3571717 Add `#include <errno.h>`, this is where `ENOMSG` is defined.